# Fixed GTK widget layout

Tags: gtk

I have a custom widget derived from a GtkVBox which depending on state contains a selection of subwidgets. I want all instances of this custom widget to be of the same height and subwidgets to always be placed at the same position inside this custom widget even if some subwidgets are not visible, i.e. if not all subwidgets are shown I want the space where subwidgets would be shown to be taken up and empty.

E.g. consider a GtkVBox which may contain up to four buttons, but sometimes only shows the first and the last button. There should be empty vertical space between the first and last button which corresponds to the space the second and third button would take if they were shown, i.e. with placholders of equivalent size in between.

As far as I understand it I have two options:

1. either I could use a GtkFixed as a container and do all positioning and sizing code myself
2. or I could create fake buttons, get a size requisition from it, and then add a dummy widget, e.g. an empty GtkLayout of equivalent size as a placeolder to the VBox

The second option is rather hackish but saves me from writing quite a bit of code, are there any downsides to it? How would you do it and why, any better ideas?

Comment: How about packing using tables? Then when you hide a widget it might leave the space empty. http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/x389.html

Comment: If the table has only a single column (and it isn't homogeneous) it will resize itself and not leave an empty space when hiding a widget.